# Kopete (0.70.90 on KDE 4.3.1) keeps disconnecting

Tags: linux, networking, kde, kopete, icq

My Kopete constantly loses my ICQ connection. There are days where it stays on for more than 10 minutes, other days it loses connection much more frequently. What could be the source of this problem?

**Edit:** I was traveling the past two weeks, and it seems the problem is related to my local connection. Except everything else works fine. I haven't been home since then so I had not yet the chance to check other networks/apps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any other services (gmail chat, msn etc) with it?
This might help to narrow down the problem, as if the others are disconnecting too then it could be a connectivity or bandwidth problem...

Have you tried using another application (such as Pidgin) to see if it has issues in connecting to ICQ and staying connected? Again, this is just a suggestion to try to help narrowing down the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using GMail as well, which stays connected. I'll try with another tool and see how it works.

Your "answer" isn't an answer though. It should have been a comment. SU doesn't work like a typical forum ;)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, still getting used to the site (and being able to add comments)

Comment: Just edited the question. I'll keep investigating as I get the chance.